# Arrow key in a textbox of a userform, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I'm working on a userform with several textboxes, which are arranged just like an excel chart.
I've set the TabIndexes, and they work perfectly with TAB/shift+TAB. However, the react of pressing arrow keys is not what I expected.
I named those textboxes like this:

```
boxA1 boxB1 boxC1 boxD1
boxA2 boxB2 boxC2 boxD2 ...
boxA3 boxB3 boxC3 boxD3
          :
          :
```

Assuming that the focus is at boxB1. When pressing the down arrow key, I wish the focus goes to boxB2, but it will go to boxA3 or something.

I've tried this code:

```
Private Sub boxB1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDown
            boxB2.SetFocus
        Case vbKeyUp
            boxA10.SetFocus
    End Select
End Sub
```

It works fine, however, if there are only several textboxes in my form, this is a great and clear solution. But there are about 70 textboxes in my form, this will make my code large and really duplicated.
Are there any parameters I can adjust to make it right?
Or is there any function I can use such as below? Just sudo, you know.

```
Private Sub name_i_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode as MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDown
            Controls("name_" & i+1).SetFocus
        Case vbKeyUp
            Controls("name_" & i-1).SetFocus
    End Select
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You would need a class module containing a generic keyDown/up handler which you tie to each textbox. For an idea of how this works, see: http://jkp-ads.com/Articles/ControlHandler00.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. Add the below two UDF's in your form module:

```
Sub SetTextBoxFocus(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Dim sPrevControl As String
    Dim sNextControl As String
    Dim sBoxToSet As String
    Dim oC As Control

    ' Cater for TAB key press. Setting it so that it behaves like vbKeyDown. Remove this If condition if not required
    If Asc(KeyCode) = 57 Then
        KeyCode = vbKeyDown
    End If

    ' We only want to check if pressed key was either vbKeyDown or vbKeyUp and the key was pressed on a TextBox
    If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" And (KeyCode = vbKeyDown Or KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Then

        With Me.ActiveControl

            ' Lets set both previous and next text box names
            If InStr(1, .Name, "boxD") > 0 Then
                sPrevControl = "boxC" & GetNumFromString(.Name)
                sNextControl = "boxA" & GetNumFromString(.Name) + 1
            ElseIf InStr(1, .Name, "boxA") > 0 Then
                sPrevControl = "boxD" & GetNumFromString(.Name) - 1
                sNextControl = "boxB" & GetNumFromString(.Name)
            Else
                sPrevControl = "box" & Chr(Asc(Mid(.Name, 4, 1)) - 1) & GetNumFromString(.Name)
                sNextControl = "box" & Chr(Asc(Mid(.Name, 4, 1)) + 1) & GetNumFromString(.Name)
            End If

            ' Bases on which key was pressed, lets set the name of the text box to move to
            Select Case KeyCode
                Case vbKeyDown: sBoxToSet = sNextControl
                Case Else: sBoxToSet = sPrevControl
            End Select

            ' Loop through all controls in the form and set the focus to the control if found
            For Each oC In Me.Controls
                If oC.Name = sBoxToSet Then
                    oC.SetFocus
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        End With
    End If

End Sub

Function GetNumFromString(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim oRe As New RegExp

    With oRe
        .pattern = "\d"
        If .Test(txt) Then GetNumFromString = .Execute(txt)(0)
    End With

End Function
```

Now, in KeyDown for each TextBox, make the following call: **`SetTextBoxFocus KeyCode`**. This should do the trick 
**NOTE:** I have `boxD` as the last text box. You should change that to whatever the last text box you have in the same row